# Run custom script when deployed Azure vm boots

Tags: python, linux, azure, docker

I'm using Azure Python SDK to deploy a Linux Vm in the Cloud. This Vm has a public IP and ssh enabled. I need to have this Vm running a custom script immediately after it boots . This script would install pip, python, docker etc and start a docker container.

How could I pass this script when deploying the vm ? / How could I instruct the vm to run this script after it has started ?

Cheers,
Steve

Comment: Stack Overflow is a site for programming and development questions. This question appears to be off-topic because it is not about programming or development. See [What topics can I ask about here](http://stackoverflow.com/help/on-topic) in the Help Center. Perhaps [Super User](http://superuser.com/) or [Unix & Linux Stack Exchange](http://unix.stackexchange.com/) would be a better place to ask.

Answer (score 3):

According to your scenario, you could use [Azure Custom Script Extension](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/virtual-machines/linux/extensions-customscript).

> The Custom Script Extension downloads and executes scripts on Azure
>   virtual machines. This extension is useful for post deployment
>   configuration, software installation, or any other configuration /
>   management task. Scripts can be downloaded from Azure storage or other
>   accessible internet location, or provided to the extension run time.

If you want to use python to do this, please refer to this [python sdk documentation](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/python/api/azure.mgmt.compute.compute.v2017_03_30.operations.virtualmachineextensionsoperations?view=azure-python#azure_mgmt_compute_compute_v2017_03_30_operations_VirtualMachineExtensionsOperations_create_or_update).

Please refer to the similar [question](https://serverfault.com/questions/874212/continuous-deployment-on-multiple-azure-vm/874324#874324).